# Show that $ \prod_{k=1}^n [1 + p_{nk}(e^{it} - 1)] \rightarrow e^{\lambda(e^{it} - 1)}, n \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: probability, analysis, limits

> Suppose that $0\leq p_{nk} \leq 1, 1 \leq k \leq n$, $\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} p_{nk} \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n p_{nk} \rightarrow \lambda$. Show that 
>   $$
> \prod_{k=1}^n [1 + p_{nk}(e^{it} - 1)] \rightarrow e^{\lambda(e^{it} - 1)}, n \rightarrow \infty
> $$

This is part of the proof of Poisson's limit theorem. I am able to show
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n [1 + p_{nk}(e^{t} - 1)] \rightarrow e^{\lambda(e^{t} - 1)}, n \rightarrow \infty
$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$: let $\delta = e^t - 1$. $(1 + p_{nk}\delta)^\frac{1}{p_{nk}}$ converges to $e^\delta$ uniformly w.r.t. $k$ as $\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} p_{nk} \rightarrow 0$, so for any $0 < \epsilon < e^\delta$, for sufficiently large $n$ we have 
$$
e^\delta - \epsilon < (1 + p_{nk}\delta)^\frac{1}{p_{nk}} < e^\delta + \epsilon,
$$
and thus
$$
(e^\delta - \epsilon)^{\sum p_{nk}} < \prod_{k=1}^n [1 + p_{nk}(e^{t} - 1)] < (e^\delta + \epsilon)^{\sum p_{nk}}
$$
By taking limit superior and inferior we have
\begin{gather*}
(e^\delta - \epsilon)^{\lambda} \leq \limsup\prod_{k=1}^n [1 + p_{nk}(e^{t} - 1)] \leq (e^\delta + \epsilon)^{\lambda}\\
(e^\delta - \epsilon)^{\lambda} \leq \liminf\prod_{k=1}^n [1 + p_{nk}(e^{t} - 1)] \leq (e^\delta + \epsilon)^{\lambda}
\end{gather*}
Then by letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ the proof is completed.

However, I cannot generalize the proof to the case when $\delta$ is defined as the complex number $\delta = e^{it} - 1$. I have considered *analytic continuation* but since $\varphi(t)$(the characteristic function) is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$, I don't think it's applicable. Could you give me some hints on the problem? Thanks for any help in advance :-)

Comment: If coupling estimates are authorized, one can show that the LHS is the characteristic function of a sum $S_n$ of Bernoulli random variables such that $P(S_n\ne T_n)\to0$, where $T_n$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda_n=\sum\limits_kp_{nk}$. Since $\lambda_n\to\lambda$, this proves the claim (with an explicit upper bound of the error).

Comment: @Did Could you be more specific? What do you mean by "coupling estimates"?

Comment: *Coupling* refers to settings where one builds various random variables (here, Bernoulli and Poisson) on a common probability space to deduce comparisons of distributions through almost sure relationships. This is a powerful tool (see *The coupling method* by Lindvall, referenced on the [WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability))).